# How can I get id_token while authorized using OAuth 2.0?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, access-token

How can I get id_token while being authorized in website (OAuth 2.0)? I am trying to send post request which is include itself client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, redirect_uri. But in reponse I didn't get "id_token". How can I managing to get "id_token"? Maybe I need to add something else to my post request? Or I need to change some details directly in url?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no ID token in Oauth 2. It was introduced by OpenID Connect.